# : Error creating bean with name 'expressionHandler'

Tags: spring, acl

I am getting error while using spring acl , i just changed some of class scope as custom scope and on deployment of application now i am getting error 
: Error creating bean with name 'expressionHandler'

full stack :

Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expressionHandler' defined in class path resource [spring-security-acl.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'permissionEvaluator' while setting bean property 'permissionEvaluator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'permissionEvaluator' defined in class path resource [spring-security-acl.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'aclService' defined in class path resource [spring-security-acl.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.LookupStrategy]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource] to required type [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.LookupStrategy]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource' to required type 'org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.LookupStrategy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource] to required type [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.LookupStrategy]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

config files
1- appConfig.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">


    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000"/>
    </bean>


    <bean name="myService" class="com.mypackage.test.business.serviceImpl.myService" scope="CustomeScope" lazy-init="true"/>


 </beans>
```

2-spring-security-acl

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <!-- Reference to a custom expression handler with ACL support -->
        <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
    </security:global-method-security>  

    <!-- A customized expression handler
        permissionEvaluator: a reference to a custom PermissionEvaluator
        roleHierarchy: defines the role order -->
    <bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler"  scope="CustomeScope"
        p:permissionEvaluator-ref="permissionEvaluator"
         /> 

    <!-- A customized PermissionEvaluator that evaluates permissions via the ACL module -->
    <bean class="com.aricent.ips.config.AclPermissionEvaluatorCustom" id="permissionEvaluator" scope="CustomeScope">
        <!-- Reference to the ACL service which performs JDBC calls to an ACL database -->
        <constructor-arg ref="aclService"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- A customized ACL service which provides default JDBC implementation -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService" id="aclService" scope="CustomeScope">
        <constructor-arg  index="0" ref="dataSourceDynamic"/>
        <constructor-arg  index="1" ref="lookupStrategy" />
        <constructor-arg  index="2" ref="aclCache"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- A lookup strategy for optimizing database queries -->
    <bean id="lookupStrategy" class="com.myPackage.test.config.BasicLookupStrategyCustom" scope="CustomeScope">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSourceDynamic"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="aclAuthorizationStrategy"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="auditLogger"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- A MySQL datasource with pooling capabalities for the ACL module -->


    <!-- An ACL cache to minimize calls to the ACL database -->   
    <bean id="aclCache" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.EhCacheBasedAclCache">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
                <property name="cacheManager" >
                    <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:shared="true" />
                </property>
                <property name="cacheName" value="aclCache"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- An ACL authorization strategy to determine whether a principal is permitted to call administrative methods -->
    <bean id="aclAuthorizationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                    <constructor-arg value="ADMIN"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                    <constructor-arg value="ADMIN"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                    <constructor-arg value="ADMIN"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- An audit logger used to log audit events -->
    <bean id="auditLogger" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger"/>

    <!-- Defines the role order -->
    <!-- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchyImpl.html -->

</beans>
```

any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: post your `spring-security-acl.xml` and other relevant config.

Comment: Cannot resolve reference to bean `'permissionEvaluator'` while setting bean property 'permissionEvaluator' -- Do you have bean with the name 'permissionEvaluator'?

Comment: its already there in acl package .

Comment: i finally solved it myself , problem was from bean's  custom scope implementations .

Comment: @PRS If you've solved it please add an answer, after another day you'll be able to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in creation of tenant object , i was putting it in a map on basis of name keyword and due to getting same name all the time i was getting one type of object i solved it by differentiating map keys

```
public class TenantScope implements Scope {

Map <String,Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
@Override
public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String tenantIdentifier = TenantThreadLocal.tenantThreadLocal.get()==null?"":TenantThreadLocal.tenantThreadLocal.get();
    System.out.println("tenantIdentifier in scope :"+tenantIdentifier);
    Object object=map.get(tenantIdentifier+name);

    if(object==null){
        object = objectFactory.getObject();
        System.out.println("object :"+object);

        map.put(tenantIdentifier+name, object);
    }
    System.out.println("returning object :"+object);
    return object;
}

@Override
public Object remove(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getConversationId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}